# The_title() Wordpress using in php script

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the_title(); from a wordpress page to use it in a php script

my code:

```
<?php 
  global $post;
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'category_name' => 'bin-o' );
  $posts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata($post); ?>
    $project_name = the_title();
    $post_id = get_page_id('$project_name');
    var_dump($project_name);
?>

<a href="<?php echo get_site_url() . '/?p=' .  $post_id  ?>"><h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
<?php the_content() ?></a>
```

The functions.php:

```
<?php 

  // Get the id of a page by its name
  function get_page_id($page_name){
    global $wpdb;
    $page_name = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '".$page_name."'");
    return $page_name;
  }
?>
```

The problem is it only gives the_title() When it is printed.
so I can't use the_title() to use it for a php script cause the_title will return NULL

how can I fix this so I can use the requested title to use this further in the php script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use [`get_the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title).

Many wordpress in-loop functions have corresponding `get_` versions, which will return the value, instead of echoing it.

Comment: As a complement to this answer, you should avoid to use WPDB to make your own query. Wordpress provide everything to help you get what ever you want from the database without having to write any SQL query (as long it's not a custom table).

Comment: Is there an other way to recieve the post id by title? because get_page_by_title() does strange things with the adminbar

Answer (score 1):

I've used this now:

```
<?php
  $project_name = trim(ucfirst(get_the_title())); //The title of current post!
  $project_info = get_page_by_title($project_name);
  $project_id = $project_info->ID;
?>

<a href="<?php echo get_site_url() . '/?p=' .  $project_id  ?>"><h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
<?php the_content() ?></a>
```

The project_info get's all the project info, project_id gets the ID out of the project info and uses that to redirect to the wanted page. so I dont have to use the functions anymore